# Spacing between letter in sectionIndexTitlesForTableView, the empty object trick not working anymore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to add spaces between letters in `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` to take all the screen height. I have found this method:

[UITableView section index spacing on iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923729/uitableview-section-index-spacing-on-ios-7?lq=1)

But it doesn't work. Has something changed?

This is my implementation (I only want to do it on iPhone 5):

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {


    float ScreenHeight=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    if (ScreenHeight==568) {

        return[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@" ", @"B",@" ", @"C",@" ", @"D",@" ", @"E",@" ", @"F",@" ", @"G",@" ", @"H",@" ", @"I",@" ", @"J",@" ", @"K",@" ", @"L",@" ", @"M",@" ", @"N",@" ", @"O",@" ", @"P",@" ", @"Q",@" ", @"R",@" ", @"S",@" ", @"T",@" ", @"U",@" ", @"V",@" ", @"W",@" ", @"X",@" ", @"Y",@" ", @"Z", nil];
    }
    else {
        return[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];

    }

}
```

EDIT

Adding one empty object each letter create a "synthetic sectionIndexTitlesForTableView view" , not all letteres are showing in the right but only someone. I think that is a default behaviour for a too long list... Anyway if i remove some empty objects (for example i erase only the lasts 5 empty objects from the array) the "synthetic view" disappear but the letter spacing in the sectionIndexTitlesForTableView don't change (is the same spacing that i have in an array without empty objects),even beetween A and B where i have left an empty object.

Comment: Define "it doesn't work." Do your titles not show up? Are they not spaced out at all? Are they not spaced out enough? Do the indexes not map to the sections properly? Does the code melt your phone and summon Cthulhu? "It doesn't work" is not an addressable bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that on a 4" iPhone screen in iOS7, the maximum number of objects that can exist in the section index titles of a full-screen table view with a navigation bar is **36**. Past that, they won't fit and they will begin "combining" into the dots that you're likely seeing. This can be shown pretty easily with a couple screen shots:

36 items will take up the whole screen's height:

[image: 36 Section Titles]

However, if you include just one more line, it will obscure/combine titles into "dots." Even though some of these dots represent a single item, they are placed throughout the entire line. My guess is that Apple figured it would look strange if they only combined two objects in the middle with a single dot. Here's the same table but with 37 section titles:

[image: 37 Section Titles]

Even if the 37th item won't cause it to use the whole screen height (because your blanks don't take as much vertical space as a letter) the OS will still combine them because it assumes that the 37th item will not fit.

So, to answer your question, the "blank" or "empty item" trick does still work, but only if your real items + empty items add up to <= 36.

---

As for how to "correct" this issue, your options are limited. You can place 10 or less empty objects spaced throughout your alphabet to maximize the space, but this would look strange (some letters would be grouped, and then a space, and then a group, a space, etc.) and would be more difficult to handle when the user actually taps on one of the section index titles.

The other option would be to increase the font size of the index titles, which one of the posters suggested in an answer in the post you linked in your question. This seems incredibly hackish based on how it's being accomplished and the number of times the method needs to be called.

## tl;dr:

The 3rd option, and **the option that I would suggest**, would be to *accept the full alphabet as it is*. It already takes up a vast majority of the vertical space and will be more in-line with how other apps would display this control. Plus you don't have to override `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:`. And you don't have to return different titles for different screen sizes.

[image]